# Can banishment work on PCs who have plane shifted to other planes?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, planes

If you plane shift to another plane, do you now count as an extraplanar creature for the purposes of spells like [banishment](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/banishment)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes**.

From the [SRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#subtype-extraplanar):

> **Extraplanar Subtype**
>
> This subtype is applied to any creature when it is on a plane other than its native plane. A creature that travels the planes can gain or lose this subtype as it goes from plane to plane. Monster entries assume that encounters with creatures take place on the Material Plane, and every creature whose native plane is not the Material Plane has the extraplanar subtype (but would not have it when on its home plane). Every extraplanar creature in this book has a home plane mentioned in its description. Creatures not labeled as extraplanar are natives of the Material Plane, and they gain the extraplanar subtype if they leave the Material Plane. No creature has the extraplanar subtype when it is on a transitive plane, such as the Astral Plane, the Ethereal Plane, or the Plane of Shadow.

So, assuming your PC is native to the material plane, if you go to, say, the plane of Air, you can be banished back to the material plane.

However, if you are on a transitive plane (Astral, Ethereal, Shadow), no creature counts as extraplanar, so no one can be banished.

Comment: It might be good to add for PCs considering *banishment* and *dismissal* as an alternative to *plane shift* that there's no indication that the spell's caster has any control over where on its home plane the banished or dismissed creature appears.

Comment: @HeyICanChan By a strict reading of *banishment* a PC couldn't use it to send his friends home since none of the PCs (presumably) are on their home plane.

Comment: @LegendaryDude But *dismissal* (which *banishment* references) doesn't have such a limitation. Likewise, I suspect most GMs would allow PCs to *banish* their friends in much the same way I expect GMs let the spell *astral projection* be cast on planes other than the Material.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I thought about including something about the fact that **where** the targets end up is unspecified, but I figured it would be a fun surprise for any PCs :)

Comment: Blasphemy, Dictum, Holy Word and Word-of-Chaos similarly banish, making creatures like Hezrou (with Blasphemy as an SLA) particularly problematic when encountered on their home plane.

Comment: Interestingly, the Holy Word line of spells specify that the banishing only works when the caster is on their home plane.

Comment: Wouldn't that be horrible: your PC party gets _Banished_ from Plane of Air, but instead of returning (for example) to Forgotten Realms, they go to Dark Sun. Because it's on the Prime Material, right? As an evil GM...